# Exception encountered while running statement: 'TextPlain' for Glue session

Tags: python, aws-glue

My team is using AWS Glue endpoints to locally develop using VS code notebooks, this morning for some reason - our endpoints get the error below. Its 3  machines (Mac, Linux and Windows) that did not update anything and just suddenly got this error when trying to use the Glue endpoint. Anyone else getting this error? Whats even stranger is that  the fourth developer, who does not have a different setup can still use the endpoint.

If I create a notebook using `jupyter notebook` and use the glue pyspark kernel there, it will work. Any attempt at updating or redownloading Python / the packages has no effect.

When I add a print to this library I can see the `Data` object is empty. If I comment this line out I am unable to see outputs from my notebook.

Anyone else getting this error?

The error:

```
Trying to create a Glue session for the kernel.
Worker Type: G.1X
Number of Workers: 2
Session ID: 6f7ecef2-de6a-44fe-bbfc-bf8b1fa53ce5
Applying the following default arguments:
--glue_kernel_version 0.35
--enable-glue-datacatalog true
--additional-python-modules great-expectations==0.15.17
--conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED
--enable-job-insights true
Waiting for session 6f7ecef2-de6a-44fe-bbfc-bf8b1fa53ce5 to get into ready status...
Session 6f7ecef2-de6a-44fe-bbfc-bf8b1fa53ce5 has been created

Exception encountered while running statement: 'TextPlain' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aws_glue_interactive_sessions_kernel/glue_pyspark/GlueKernel.py", line 163, in do_execute
    self._send_output(statement_output["Data"]["TextPlain"])
KeyError: 'TextPlain'
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Support said 0.37 works for one of the customers, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe you can give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but I managed to fix it by
downgrading to python3.9 from python3.10,
updated aws-glue-sessions to 0.37.0 from 0.35.0
and downgrading psutil to 5.9.1.
There could potentially be other issues but those should be apparent in the "Output" tab in VSCode.

Comment: This worked! quite strange as 3.10 worked before but I can confirm that downgrading from 3.10 to 3.9 works. For me at least 3.8 did not work.